# Property of Bernstein polynomials that $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k}{n}B_k^n(t) = t, n > 0$

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, summation

I see this identity pop up a, but I have not seen a proof for it, nor can I prove it myself. The only progress I have made is that $\frac{k}{n}{n \choose k} = {n - 1 \choose k - 1}$, so that $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k}{n}B_k^n(t) = \sum_{k=1}^n{n - 1 \choose k - 1}t^k(1 - t)^{n - k}$. How can the identity be proven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote that:    $\ \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k}{n}B_k^n(t) = \sum_{k=1}^n{n - 1 \choose k - 1}t^k(1 - t)^{n - k}$

Then:  $\ \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k}{n}B_k^n(t) = t \sum_{k=1}^n{n - 1 \choose k - 1}t^{k-1}(1 - t)^{n - k} = t \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}{n - 1 \choose p}t^{p}(1 - t)^{n - 1-p} =t$